# How to come back to the root UIViewController in a UINavigationViewController chain?

Tags: ios

I've a sequence of UIViewControllers pushed by a NavigationController.

What's the best way to come back to the home ViewController without having to go back through all chain of UIViewControllers ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)]
```

Comment: Thanks. One more question: what if the controller I'm interested in is not actually in the navigationController stack. Should I remove all of them and add a new one ?

Comment: How is it 'connected' the navigationController stack? Obviously the method I posted will move to the first view on the stack.

Comment: 1) It is the second one. ( 2) Also, what if I need to load a new navigationController which is not on the stack ? How can I get rid of the stack and just load such controller ?)

Comment: @Patrick - Please read the fine manuals. See "Pushing and Popping Stack Items" in Apple's UINavigationController class reference. When you bother to look up BlueMeanie's suggested method, you'll find others.